# How to force a rollback after the ADF data warning answer

Tags: javascript, javabeans, oracle-adf

here is my question.

Is there a way to force a rollback after the user clicked on the "leave this page" button generated by the uncommitted data warning in ADF?

For some reason, when my user save a row with some change, sometime it comeback with an error, the change is then pending on the database with a lock on the row. If the user then close the browser or leave the page, the row is kept locked...

I try to use the uncommitted data warning feature to help, but since it doesn't do a rollback when the user decide to leave, it doesn't fix my lock issue...

I try to use the javascript window.onbeforeunload to show a confirm message before leaving the page to force a rollback, but if the user decide to not leave then there is no way for me to prevent the user from leaving the page...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to leave ?")){
        AdfCustomEvent.queue(AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('f1'), "customRollback", {}, true);
    } else { 
        e.preventDefault();e.returnValue = "";
    }
};
```

if I use the window.onbeforeunload function but simply use it to display the real message generated by the browser, but then I get no feedback if the user decide to leave the page just like with the uncommitted data warning...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    return "Are you sure you want to quit";
};
```

I would like to have a better solution, but so far all I can see is to do a rollback everytime the user leave the page, but that will also trigger if the user refresh the page with f5, which is not optimal...

I was hoping I could have a hook in the backbean that would be able to handle when the user leave the page and do the rollback there maybe, base on the uncommitted datawarning message...

If anybody got a solution for me, I'm ready to check it out.
Thanks in advance